# Mysql delete with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Delete: can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

I'm trying to delete some rows, but is currently not in success.

```
DELETE FROM product_pictures 
WHERE picture = (SELECT picture FROM product_pictures WHERE id = ?)
```

You can't specify target table 'product_pictures' for update in `FROM` clause

I've never seen this error message before, nor has I been able to find some useful info about what I'm doing wrong.

Example of rows:

```
ID    Picture
19    picture-grey.jpg
20    picture-grey.jpg
21    picture-grey.jpg
```

Comment: Please can you confirm if you just want to delete rows with the given id or if you have a more complicated requirement.

Comment: @kris: Or you want to delete all rows that have same `picture` with the row having `id=?`

Comment: Doesn't the link (mentioned above): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause answer your question?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Distinct, so it doesnt make much sense to me..

Comment: The 2 answers by Cheekysoft there are exactly what zerkms and I answered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE a 
FROM product_pictures AS a
  JOIN product_pictures AS b
    ON b.picture = a.picture
WHERE b.id = ?
```

or:

```
DELETE a 
FROM product_pictures AS a
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT picture
      FROM product_pictures
      WHERE id = ?
    ) AS b
    ON b.picture = a.picture
```

Answer (score 10):

```
DELETE FROM product_pictures 
WHERE picture = (SELECT picture FROM (SELECT picture FROM product_pictures WHERE id = ?) x)
```

This cheat will fool mysql analyzer

Comment: Atleast it get's me another kind of error: Every derived table must have its own alias :)

Comment: @kris: so add an alias for nested query (updated query with `x` alias)

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a loop in it. Why don't you just do

```
DELETE FROM product_pictures
WHERE id = ?
```